# How to transpose rows to columns on MySQL with specific date range

Tags: mysql, pivot, transpose

I have this table:

```
user_id  date        total
1        2016-07-01  2
1        2016-08-01  4
2        2016-07-01  2
2        2016-08-01  5
3        2016-07-01  2
3        2016-08-01  3
4        2016-07-01  4
4        2016-08-01  3
5        2016-07-01  1
5        2016-08-01  5
```

and I want to transpose this table with this format:

```
userid  2016-07-01  2016-08-01
1       2           4
2       2           5
3       2           3
4       4           3
5       1           5
```

I'm using this query:

```
select 
user_id,
CASE WHEN MONTH(date)=7 then total ELSE 0 END as Jul,
CASE WHEN MONTH(date)=8 then total ELSE 0 END as Agust
from table_data
order by user_id
```

but the result is:

```
userid  2016-07-01  2016-08-01
1       2           0
1       0           4
2       2           0
2       0           5
3       2           0
3       0           3
4       4           0
4       0           3
5       1           0
5       0           5
```

How this query, I want to display to web using PHP.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered here in SO a number of times. Pls do some research before asking a question next time!

Comment: @Shadow thx for the [ping](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33014006#33014006) :p

Comment: sory, but my result is not true, please help me

Comment: @tomy just add `group by user_id`